# Java android - SocketIO xhr pool error / web socket error on Flask-socketio 5.0.1

Tags: java, android, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm working on this amazing project. Everything is ok with the web browser, docker, nginx... but currently got stuck at android java client. It keep response everytime make a socketio session:

```
    D/socketio: xhr poll error
    V/socketio: xhr poll error -> Errors :: a.a.b.a.a: xhr poll error
```

build.gradle:

```
    implementation 'io.socket:engine.io-client:2.0.0'
    implementation 'io.socket:socket.io-client:2.0.0'
```

import:

```
    import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;
    import io.socket.engineio.client.Socket;
    import io.socket.engineio.client.Transport;
    import io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling;
    import io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR;
    import io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket;
```

Android studio - Java code (client):

```
    Socket.Options options = new Socket.Options();
    options.transports = new String[]{PollingXHR.NAME, Polling.NAME, WebSocket.NAME};
    Log.d("socketio", "socketio: " + options.toString());
    try {
        socket = new Socket("http://10.10.10.212/socket.io/", options);
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_OPEN, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.i("socketio", "open");
            }
        });
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Exception err = (Exception) args[0];
                Log.i("socketio", "error:" + err.toString());
            }
        });
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_PACKET, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.i("socketio", "packet");
            }
        });

        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_DRAIN, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.i("socketio", "drain");
            }
        });
        socket.open();
        Log.i("socketio", "open...");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Flask Python socketio server:

```
    flask_socketio==5.0.1
    python-engineio==4.0.0
    python-socketio==5.0.4
```

Web browser work perfectly with:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure your Android client has been updated to the latest version of the Socket.IO protocol? There's been an update recently and is not backwards compatible. The JavaScript and Python packages you are using are all for the new version of the protocol. My guess is that Android hasn't been upgraded yet, so you may need to downgrade Python. The Flask-SocketIO docs have a version compatibility table that might help.

Comment: @Miguel. Thanks for great suggestion. I tried a lot version and it seem not working. I think better to wait for latest official release. I’m cheating on it currently :(